# When to use static methods over objects

Tags: java, oop, object, static

Until now I wrote my programs by using only static methods. I haven't abused the principles of OOP at all. My question is, when should I start working with objects instead of using static methods? Because it seems to me that using static methods makes my life easier, but I might be wrong.

Comment: If you posted some code examples of your code, maybe we could see how your code could benefit from using objects.

Comment: Keep on going with static methods if they make your life easier. I always start my design the same way and wait for a real concern to force objects on me. It usually does happen, though.

Comment: Well it seems to me that everything can be written using static methods. But I might be wrong, as I said.
@MarkoTopolnik In what case do you get forced to use objects?

Comment: One significant barrier is multithreading: with everything static you can't offer thread-local state without the clumsy ThreadLocals. That's where I usually start introducing objects.

Comment: Another strong attractor are inversion-of-control containers like Spring.

Comment: a program made up of static methods is going to be very tightly coupled and hard to test parts in isolation

Comment: A third, very important reason is leveraging dynamic dispatch, which can make your code much cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static Methods make your live easier, because you dont have to worry about Accessability in different scopes (not talking about private/public Methods - static methods are ALWAYS there, no matter in which context you are).  Basically every OOP Method can be converted to a static method, using the object as one of the parameters. Also each Static method, having an object as a parameter could be converted to a method on the object instance.

People have been developing Apps, before any sort of "OOP" was known, so its not a "musst have".

General speaking:
Does your method require "Object Properties"? Use an Object/instance method.
Does your method NOT require Object Properties? Use a static method.

OOP makes your live easier, when you have coupled data (like a person has a certain fore- and surename and an email adress -> create an object with those 3 attributes). Instead of passing 3 Parameters to a method, you could implement a method without parameters on the object, and have access to all 3 values.

You would not run into trouble, swapping forenames or email adresses somewhere. Your Object clearly keeps track of data relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write everything using static methods. Just as one example, if you create a `JFrame` and want to use a control that custom paints itself, you must create a subclass of at least `JComponent` and override the paint methods.

Comment: So in essence, the complexity of the problem or what technologies you want to use decide it?

Comment: That's because `JFrame` is already an object. You should instead prove that it is *impossible* to design a GUI framework without objects.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need any state in your class, static methods are fine. It is also harder to test.